solana program write-buffer always failed

when run solana program write-buffer, error is
Error: Account allocation failed: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds

or like the pic show. i tried with a helius and quicknode rpc, i have enough 20 sol in wallet. i tried two weeks and cannot upgrade my program.

hey, what version of solana are you using? Try upgrading to the latest version and see if that helps.
